# How to delay import python file

Tags: python

I have two python files and I am import one into another with:

```
 in test1.py
 import test2




  test2.py

   import os
   from socket import *
   host = "192.168.1.253" # set to IP address of target computer
   port = 8081
   addr = (host, port)
   UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
   data = "102"
   UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
   UDPSock.close()
```

Is there any way to import test2.py with delay time in seconds?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: ...why would you want to have a delay? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Ask about the thing you want to achieve, not the solution you think is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it *is* possible to delay an `import` simply by putting slower stuff above it in your file, it's probably not a good solution to your real problem, which is that you want the *behavior* that is triggered by the import to be delayed.

A better way to do that is to put that behavior in a function, which you can then call at any time after doing the import. The import is no longer directly triggering the behavior, so you can leave the `import` statement at the top of the file where most people will expect it to be.

Here are some more simplified examples.

A version based on your current code:

library.py

```
print("doing stuff")
```

script.py

```
import library # oops, this triggers the print too soon
```

An alternative script with a delay before it imports the library (which is what you're specifically asking for, though not really a great idea):

script.py:

```
import time

time.sleep(10)  # this does the delaying

import library  # this triggers the print, but it's unexpected to see an import here
```

A better solution is to move the behavior of the library into a function, so the time you do the import no longer matters (only the time you call the function):

library.py:

```
def stuff():
    print("doing stuff")
```

script.py:

```
import time

import library  # we can do the import whenever we want, doesn't cause any printing

time.sleep(10)
library.stuff() # do the stuff here
```

If you wanted the `library` module to also be usable as a script, you could add this code to the bottom of the file, so that it calls the function itself some times:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    stuff()
```

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` line is a bit of boilerplate that checks if the current module is the `__main__` module of the program (which is true if it's being run as a script). If instead the module is being imported, that condition will be false, and so the function won't get run (until the real script decides to call it).

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

time.sleep(9) #delay for 9 seconds

import test2
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I am downvoting because this is definitely an XY problem and that answer will probably end up being the right answer to the wrong problem.

Comment: @Chris Provided they have already two upvotes, the reputation penalty is fairly small. Furthermore, I'm giving a clear explanation of why I am downvoting, I think it is important for a new contributor to learn about XY problems. Finally, if that turns out to be, for some reason, the correct answer I will retract my downvote. It is ok to be downvoted, their is no shame in that.